# Improve readability and quality of javascript functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function, which merges a number of HTML tables into a single results table using a value common to all pre-merge tables.

[image]

I am now looking to improve the speed and reliability of my javascript function. The function `gatherData()` loops through each pre-merge table and places the data into an object structure for each table respectively. The function `results()` loops through these objects, and populates the results table using the common value, in this example the date.

This code was written at speed and I am aware it's pretty ugly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    gatherData();
    results();
});

function gatherData(){
    data = [];

    tables = $('.before').find('table');

    $(tables).each(function(index){
        table = [];

        var headers = $(this).find('tr:first');
        var headerText = [];
        headerText.push($(headers).find('td:nth-child(1)').text());     
        headerText.push($(headers).find('td:nth-child(2)').text());
        table.push(headerText)
        $(this).find('tr').each(function(index){
            var rowContent = [];
            if (index != 0){
                $(this).find('td').each(function(index){
                    rowContent.push($(this).text());
                })
            }
            table.push(rowContent)
        })
        data.push({table: table})
    });
}

function results(){
    var results = $('.after1').find('thead');

    $(results).append("<th>" + data[0].table[0][0] + "</th>");

    for (i in data){
        console.log(i)
        $(results).append("<th>" + data[i].table[0][1] + "</th>");
    }

    var b = data[i].table.length;
    var rowString = "";
    for (a = 2; a < b; a++){
        rowString = rowString + "<tr>";
        rowString = rowString + "<td>" + data[i].table[a][0] + "</td>"
        for (i in data){
            rowString = rowString + "<td>" + data[i].table[a][1] + "</td>"
        }
        rowString = rowString + "</tr>"
    }
    $('.after1').append(rowString)
}
```

The object(s) are structured as follows:

[image]

**For information**

The actual data for each table starts at `data[i].table[2]`, and within this the date is `data[i].table[2][0]` and the value for that date is `data[i].table[2][1]`. This is why the `a` var in this for loop `for (a = 2; a < data[i].table.length; a++)` begins at 2.

[Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXbLMv) is a link to my CodePen.

Comment: Hey, welcome back! And your question is?

Comment: Question should rather be posted on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your code doesn't really work in the way one expects, and furthermore it's very hard-coded in a way (the join key is always the first column and it only takes into account the first two columns). [This pen](http://codepen.io/souldreamer/pen/BjNXGB) shows exactly how it would fail to provide the proper result one would expect.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  gatherData();
  results();
});

function gatherData() {
  data = [];

  tables = $('.before').find('table');

  $(tables).each(function(index) {
    table = [];

    var headers = $(this).find('tr:first');
    var headerText = [];
    headerText.push($(headers).find('td:nth-child(1)').text());
    headerText.push($(headers).find('td:nth-child(2)').text());
    table.push(headerText)
    $(this).find('tr').each(function(index) {
      var rowContent = [];
      if (index != 0) {
        $(this).find('td').each(function(index) {
          rowContent.push($(this).text());
        })
      }
      table.push(rowContent)
    })
    data.push({
      table: table
    })
  });
}

function results() {
  var results = $('.after1').find('thead');

  $(results).append("<th>" + data[0].table[0][0] + "</th>");

  for (i in data) {
    console.log(i)
    $(results).append("<th>" + data[i].table[0][1] + "</th>");
  }

  var b = data[i].table.length;
  var rowString = "";
  for (a = 2; a < b; a++) {
    rowString = rowString + "<tr>";
    rowString = rowString + "<td>" + data[i].table[a][0] + "</td>"
    for (i in data) {
      rowString = rowString + "<td>" + data[i].table[a][1] + "</td>"
    }
    rowString = rowString + "</tr>"
  }
  $('.after1').append(rowString)
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Formatter.js</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>


  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="page-header">Formatter.js <small>DPD reports</small></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container before">
    <h3>Before</h3>
    <TABLE border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 alignment="">
      <TBODY>
        <TR>
          <TD>x-value</TD>
          <TD>La</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>1</TD>
          <TD>a</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>2</TD>
          <TD>b</TD>
        </TR>
      </TBODY>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 alignment="">
      <TBODY>
        <TR>
          <TD>x-value</TD>
          <TD>Lx</TD>
          <TD>Lxx</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>1</TD>
          <TD>x</TD>
          <TD>xx</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>3</TD>
          <TD>y</TD>
          <TD>yy</TD>
        </TR>
      </TBODY>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 alignment="">
      <TBODY>
        <TR>
          <TD>Random</TD>
          <TD>Lz</TD>
          <TD>Lzz</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>1</TD>
          <TD>z</TD>
          <TD>zz</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>2</TD>
          <TD>t</TD>
          <TD>tt</TD>
        </TR>
      </TBODY>
    </TABLE>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="container after">
    <h3>After</h3>
    <table class="table after1">
      <thead>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="formatter4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

To summarize, for the tables:

```
x-value | La    x-value | Lx | Lxx    Random | Lz | Lzz
--------+----   --------+----+-----   -------+----+-----
1       | a     1       | x  | xx     1      | z  | zz
2       | b     3       | y  | yy     2      | t  | tt
```

Most people would expect the following result (with or without line 2 and/or 3, depending on what you actually want to do with the data):

```
x-value | La | Lx | Lxx 
--------+----+----+-----
1       | a  | x  | xx  
2       | b  |    |     
3       |    | y  | yy
```

Your code mixes the tables (just concatenates them, without regard for the actual column header (if it's `x-value` or not), without regard for the actual value that the tables are joined on (just the position of the row in the table, so `row 1` will be concatenated with `row 2` no matter what), and it ignores all columns other than the first two, producing the following result:

```
x-value | La | Lx | Lz 
--------+----+----+----
1       | a  | x  | z  
2       | b  | y  | t
```

As I felt like trying my hand at it, [this pen](http://codepen.io/souldreamer/pen/zrGgqo) contains a much more complete solution.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 createResultsTable($('.after1'), gatherData($('.before').find('table'), 'x-value'), sortDatesDescending);
});

function sortDatesDescending(keys) {
  function getDate(dateStr) {
    var date = dateStr.match(/^(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})$/);
    return new Date(date[3], date[2], date[1]);
  }
  return keys.sort(function (key1, key2) { key1 = getDate(key1); key2 = getDate(key2); return key1 < key2 ? 1 : key1 == key2 ? 0 : -1; });
}

function gatherData(tables, joinColumn){
 var data = {};
  var dataHeaders = [];

 tables.each(function(index) {
    var table = $(this);
  var headerText = [];
    
    var joinColumnIndex = -1;
    table.find('tr:first').find('td').each(function(index, header) {
      header = header.innerText;
      if (header === joinColumn) joinColumnIndex = index;
      headerText.push(header);
    });
    if (joinColumnIndex < 0) return;
    
  table.find('tr').each(function(index){
      if (index === 0) return;
   var rowContent = [];
      $(this).find('td').each(function(index){
        rowContent.push(this.innerText);
      });
    data[rowContent[joinColumnIndex]] = data[rowContent[joinColumnIndex]] || [];
      data[rowContent[joinColumnIndex]].push(rowContent);
  })
    dataHeaders.push(headerText);
 });
  console.log(data, dataHeaders);// here goes
  return {data: data, headers: dataHeaders, joinColumn: joinColumn};
}

function createResultsTable(resultsTable, data, orderFunction) {
  var resultsHead = '<thead><th>'+data.joinColumn+'</th>';
  var resultsBody = '<tbody>';
  data.headers.forEach(function (headers) {
    headers.forEach(function (header) {
      if (header !== data.joinColumn) resultsHead += '<th>'+header+'</th>';
    });
  });
  resultsHead += '</thead>';
  (orderFunction ? orderFunction(Object.keys(data.data)) : Object.keys(data.data))
    .forEach(function (joinValue) {
    resultsBody += '<tr><td>'+joinValue+'</td>';
    data.data[joinValue].forEach(function (subData, tableIndex) {
      data.headers[tableIndex].forEach(function (header, index) {
        if (header === data.joinColumn) return;
        resultsBody += '<td>'+subData[index]+'</td>';
      })
    });
    resultsBody += '</tr>';
  });
  resultsBody += '</tbody>';
  resultsTable.html(resultsHead+resultsBody);
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Formatter.js</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>


  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="page-header">Formatter.js <small>DPD reports</small></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container before">
    <h3>Before</h3>
    <TABLE border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 alignment="">
      <TBODY>
        <TR>
          <TD>x-value</TD>
          <TD>Operational Planned</TD>
          <td>Extra data</td>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>09/11/2015</TD>
          <TD>0</TD>
          <TD>extra1</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>10/11/2015</TD>
          <TD>0</TD>
          <TD>extra2</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>11/11/2015</TD>
          <TD>66358</TD>
          <TD>extra3</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>12/11/2015</TD>
          <TD>65990</TD>
          <TD>extra4</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>13/11/2015</TD>
          <TD>55993</TD>
          <TD>extra5</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>14/11/2015</TD>
          <TD>0</TD>
          <TD>extra6</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>15/11/2015</TD>
          <TD>0</TD>
          <TD>extra7</TD>
        </TR>
      </TBODY>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 alignment="">
      <TBODY>
        <TR>
          <TD>x-value</TD>
          <TD>Actual</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>09/11/2015</TD>
          <TD>0</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>10/11/2015</TD>
          <TD>0</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>11/11/2015</TD>
          <TD>62202</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>12/11/2015</TD>
          <TD>59261</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>13/11/2015</TD>
          <TD>49119</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>14/11/2015</TD>
          <TD>0</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>15/11/2015</TD>
          <TD>0</TD>
        </TR>
      </TBODY>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 alignment="">
      <TBODY>
        <TR>
          <TD>not the x-value</TD>
          <TD>something</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>09/11/2015</TD>
          <TD>0</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>10/11/2015</TD>
          <TD>0</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>11/11/2015</TD>
          <TD>62202</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>12/11/2015</TD>
          <TD>59261</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>13/11/2015</TD>
          <TD>49119</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>14/11/2015</TD>
          <TD>0</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>15/11/2015</TD>
          <TD>0</TD>
        </TR>
      </TBODY>
    </TABLE>
    <TABLE border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 alignment="">
      <TBODY>
        <TR>
          <TD>x-value</TD>
          <TD>Financial Plan</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>09/11/2015</TD>
          <TD>0</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>10/11/2015</TD>
          <TD>0</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>11/11/2015</TD>
          <TD>0</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>12/11/2015</TD>
          <TD>890</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>13/11/2015</TD>
          <TD>0</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>14/11/2015</TD>
          <TD>3562</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>15/11/2015</TD>
          <TD>7821</TD>
        </TR>
      </TBODY>
    </TABLE>
    <table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 alignment="">
      <tr>
        <td>Additional info</td><td>x-value</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>marked</td><td>11/11/2015</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>important</td><td>09/11/2015</td>
      </tr>
    </table>      
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="container after">
    <h3>After</h3>
    <table class="table after1">
      <thead>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="formatter4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This code:

- allows tables with any number of columns to be joined
- matches the data on the columns with the column name specified in the function parameter
- allows the join column to be anywhere in the table (it can be the first, second, or whichever column is actually correctly named)
- ignores tables that don't have the specified join column
- is more general, allowing you to pass in an array of which tables are the input and which table is the output
- additionally, it allows you to define an ordering/filtering function on the keys of the resulting array (careful, you can't change their actual values, just order and filter them). Just leave the parameter out if you don't want the functionality

Hope it helps, it was a fun project. :)